# input type number restriction to an INTEGER in jsp

Tags: validation, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, numberformatexception

I have a `fill.jsp` file, in which I have the below code:

```
<div class="user-values">           <!-- for user's monthly gross pay -->
    <label for="grossPay">Monthly gross pay: </label>
    $<input id="grossPay" type="number" name="grossPay" placeholder="0.0 or greater" step="0.01" value="${grossPay}">
    <span class="req">*</span>
</div>

<div class="user-values">           <!-- for error message -->
    <p class="msg">${message2}</p>
</div>
            
<div class="user-values">           <!-- for user's dependents -->
    <label for="noOfDependents">Number of dependents: </label>
    <input id="noOfDependents" type="number" name="dependents" placeholder="0 or greater" step="1" value="${dependents}">
    <span class="req">*</span>
</div>

<div class="user-values">           <!-- for error message -->
    <p class="msg">${message3}</p>
</div>
```

The "Monthly gross pay" accepts double values. The "Number of Dependents" should accept only integers.

When I run this code: if I fill the number 2 or 2. for "Number of Dependents" and hit calculate, the calculation is processed successfully by my servlet.

However, if I fill the number of double value 2.1 or 2.2 or 3.1, and so on, I get the below error in my form:

[image: JSP Form error]

MY FIRST PROBLEM:
When I enter the number of double value 2.0 or 3.0 or 4.0, etc., I get a `NumberFormatException`

```
Type: class java.lang.NumberFormatException
Message: For input string: "2.0"
```

Why am I not getting the error similar to the image above? Or, why is my processing not successful with 2.0? Please suggest a solution so that I can avoid the exception for values such as 1.0 or 2.0 or 3.0, and so on?

MY SECOND PROBLEM:
The value part in both input types in my `fill.jsp` file is giving me the below warning in NetBeans IDE:

```
"Bad value " " for attribute "value" on element "input": Expected a minus sign or a digit but saw " " instead."
```

How can I try to avoid this warning?

Please note: my program runs properly even with the warning.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I have made more clarification in the question.

Comment: The new answer seems to compile just fine.

Comment: I am still working on it. Will let you know if it works fine.

Comment: Alright. Good to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer:

In my servlet I had a part of code: The "dependents" input box on the client-side takes in a value of 2.0, which is received as a String at the server-side.

```
String dependentNum = request.getParameter("dependents");
user.setDependents(Integer.parseInt(dependentNum));
```

For some reason, the second line of code was throwing a NumberFormatException for me. So, I changed the second line in my servlet code to:

```
user.setDependents((int) Double.parseDouble(dependentNum));
```

I don't know why the Integer object was having a problem with accepting the String value of 2.0 and converting it to 2. The workaround was to just convert the String value 2.0 to a double and cast it to an int, and I avoid getting the NumberFormatException completely.

However, I am still unable to understand, why can't the same validation error message show up as in the image for double values like 2.0, 3.0, when it can show for double values like 2.1, 3.2, etc., as below:

[image: Validation error]

Comment: I did some digging, and according to the Mozilla Developer's website, **If you try to enter a number with a decimal (such as "1.0"), it will be considered invalid.** (When the step is "1", or course) This convinces me that this is a bug. You can see more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

Answer (score 0):

Input type number allows 2.0 because it theoretically is an integer, unlike 2.1, which is a double.

```
2.0 -> 2
```

However, on the server side, it does raise errors because Integers can't have tailing zeroes, or periods.

In this case, you should probably strip the tailing zeroes.

You can use a substring to cut it, and then convert it back to an Integer.

For example:

```
double number = 2.0;
int newnumber = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(number).substring(0, 1));
```

So the servlet should look like this:

```
String dependents = req.getParameter("dependents");
double dependentsd = Double.parseDouble(dependents);
int numofDependents = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(number).substring(0, 1));
```

You can verify with this test case:

```
String dependents = "2.0";
double dependentsd = Double.parseDouble(dependents);
int numofDependents = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dependentsd).substring(0, 1));
System.out.println(numofDependents);
```

Or you can just cast the double to an int, like the following:

```
(int) Double.parseDouble(dependentNum)
```

Comment: It still gives me the NumberFormatException.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show what to add in the servlet.

Comment: Yes I am doing it like that only.

Comment: @SamVitare Hold up - it's working perfectly for me. I've added a test case.

Comment: I think my code is not even reaching the condition. I am going through it, trying to make it work.

Comment: Alright. Tell me if you have any other problems. I'm happy to help

Comment: I tested your code by creating a separate class and it works there. However, I think in my code, when I am entering everything else, it processes fine, gives me proper errors, like validations, etc. Except, when I enter 2.0 or 3.0, etc., something is happening. I believe when I enter those values, it does not even reach my servlet and something is happening in between and directly triggering the exception. I am unable to understand what is happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221611/discussion-between-aniox-and-sam-vitare).

Comment: I believe my answer did in fact solve the issue, as you pointed out when you created another class. If so, would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: please see the solution that I figured out. Thanks a lot for your time and help.